# beginner Java REST 404 error

Tags: java, rest

Newbie in trying to set up a REST service in Java. I created a simple java program and deployed the war file in apache-tomcat-8.5.5 (under the apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps dir). But when I try to access the REST service (http://localhost:8081/SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue), get a 404 error. 
(Starting the tomcat on port 8081
{Had wanted to do a POST - using Postman,but was getting error, then added a GET method to verify, but still got error)

The Java file:

```
package sampproj;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("sampproj")
public class WSPostSer {
    public WSPostSer() {
        super();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("devpost")
    public String createTemp (String devName){
        System.out.println (" in reate");
        return "heloo" + devName;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/uservalue")
    public String welcomeResource (@PathParam("uservalue") String username){    
        System.out.println("  welcomeResource ");   
        return "heloo Get " + username; 
    }
}
```

The web xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>SampleRS</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>sampproj</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

The lib (jars) that are:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjg3b.png)

> Log file
>   ***localhost_access_log.2016-09-10:***    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:16:56 +0530] "POST /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/devpost
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 1052    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:18:46 +0530]
>   "POST /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/devpost HTTP/1.1" 404 1052
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:24:57 +0530] "GET
>   /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue HTTP/1.1" 404 1056  0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
>   - - [10/Sep/2016:08:25:04 +0530] "GET /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/hell HTTP/1.1" 404 1046     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:25 +0530]
>   "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11450    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:26
>   +0530] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5926    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:26 +0530] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:26 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 21630   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:27 +0530]
>   "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - -
>   [10/Sep/2016:08:29:27 +0530] "GET /asf-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 17811
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:27 +0530] "GET /bg-upper.png
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 3103    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:27 +0530]
>   "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - -
>   [10/Sep/2016:08:29:27 +0530] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:29:42 +0530] "GET /SampleRS
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 1008    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:08:30:02 +0530]
>   "GET /SampleRS HTTP/1.1" 404 1008     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - -
>   [10/Sep/2016:15:49:20 +0530] "GET /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 1056    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:15:49:20 +0530]
>   "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - -
>   [10/Sep/2016:16:07:42 +0530] "GET /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue/df
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 1062    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:16:07:49 +0530]
>   "GET /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue=df HTTP/1.1" 404 1062
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:16:22:41 +0530] "GET
>   /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/user HTTP/1.1" 404 1046   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - -
>   [10/Sep/2016:17:40:07 +0530] "GET /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 1062    0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:17:43:08 +0530]
>   "GET /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1062
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:18:04:23 +0530] "GET
>   /SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1062
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:18:04:31 +0530] "GET
>   /WSwebapp/SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1080
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:18:04:40 +0530] "GET
>   /WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1008
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:18:09:10 +0530] "GET
>   /WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1008
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:18:20:25 +0530] "GET
>   /WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1008
>     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2016:18:21:04 +0530] "GET
>   /WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me HTTP/1.1" 404 1008
>
> ***catalina.2016-09-10:***    10-Sep-2016 17:45:33.158 INFO [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\WSwebapp.war has
>   finished in 2,632 ms  10-Sep-2016 17:45:33.235 INFO [Thread-5]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8081"]     10-Sep-2016 17:45:33.248 INFO [Thread-5]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"]  10-Sep-2016 17:45:33.259 INFO [Thread-5]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8081"]     10-Sep-2016 17:45:33.267 INFO [Thread-5]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"]  10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.249 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.5   10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.253 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
>   Aug 31 2016 19:51:16 UTC  10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.253 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.5.5.0   10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.254 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Windows 7     10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.254 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   6.1   10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.255 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64     10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.255 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre     10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.256 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_91-b15   10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.256 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation    10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.256 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5    10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.257 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5    10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.260 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048   10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.262
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\conf\logging.properties
>     10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.264 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager     10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.268 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5  10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:11.273 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5  10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:11.278 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\temp    10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:11.283 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR
>   based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in
>   production environments was not found on the java.library.path:
>   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program
>   Files\Broadcom\Broadcom
>   802.11;;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;.     10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:11.634 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]    10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:11.950 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read    10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.957 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]  10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read    10-Sep-2016 17:57:11.985 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization
>   processed in 1694 ms  10-Sep-2016 17:57:12.061 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina  10-Sep-2016 17:57:12.065 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5   10-Sep-2016 17:57:12.135 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web
>   application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\WSwebapp.war
>     10-Sep-2016 17:57:15.713 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.    10-Sep-2016 17:57:16.210 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom
>   Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using
>   [SHA1PRNG] took [305] milliseconds.   10-Sep-2016 17:57:16.264 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web
>   application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\WSwebapp.war has
>   finished in 4,128 ms  10-Sep-2016 17:57:16.267 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\docs     10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:16.324 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\docs has
>   finished in 58 ms     10-Sep-2016 17:57:16.325 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\examples
>     10-Sep-2016 17:57:17.600 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\examples has
>   finished in 1,275 ms  10-Sep-2016 17:57:17.601 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\host-manager
>     10-Sep-2016 17:57:17.687 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\host-manager
>   has finished in 86 ms     10-Sep-2016 17:57:17.688 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\manager
>     10-Sep-2016 17:57:17.761 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\manager has
>   finished in 74 ms     10-Sep-2016 17:57:17.762 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\ROOT     10-Sep-2016
>   17:57:20.655 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was
>   scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this
>   logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were
>   found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time.    10-Sep-2016 17:57:20.766 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\ROOT has
>   finished in 3,004 ms  10-Sep-2016 17:57:20.777 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   [http-nio-8081]   10-Sep-2016 17:57:20.828 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   [ajp-nio-8009]    10-Sep-2016 17:57:20.864 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 8874 ms

Comment: Should be `@Path("/sampproj")`, i.e. you should add a forward slash

Comment: Also, since you have defined `@PathParam("uservalue")`,  change `@Path("/uservalue")` to `@Path("/uservalue/${uservalue}")` and invoke URL like this: http://localhost:8081/SampleRS/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me. Assuming the context is indeed `SampleRS`.

Comment: Ori - made the changes you suggested and replaced with teh new war file still not working. How do I verify the context you mentioned?

Comment: the dir is apache-tomcat-8.5.5\webapps\WSwebapp\.. so tried http://localhost:8081/WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me and http://localhost:8081/WSwebapp/rest/SampleRS/sampproj/uservalue/me - both did not work

Comment: If you have `WSwebapp` dir under `webapps`, the URL should indeed be `localhost:8081/WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/uservalue/me`. Without any further info such as logs, it's hard to say what's going on wrong.

Comment: Ori - updated the post with the log files.. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("{uservalue}")
public String welcomeResource (@PathParam("uservalue") String username){
    System.out.println("  welcomeResource ");
    return "heloo Get " + username;
}
```

Your war file name is WSwebapp.war so type following URL in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8081/WSwebapp/rest/sampproj/me
```

and you should see `heloo Get me` :)

Comment: Or rename the war file to SampleRS.war.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need constructor for rest service class and add scope. Also you can try adding index page and access it. This way you can be sure that there is no problem with your server or the way you are trying to access it.